# Kotlin Android Studio Wait for a function to finish before calling another

Tags: android, multithreading, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I am trying to do an edit profile function where I am required to wait for the edit function to be COMPLETED before running the finish() method and returning to the view profile activity screen.

However, I am having issues where the toast is only being printed after the activity is finished and i am already directed to the view profile activity

```
        submitBtn.setOnClickListener()
    {
        runBlocking { // start main coroutine
            val job =GlobalScope.launch { // launch a new coroutine in background and continue
                delay(5000L)
                    val intent = Intent(this@editProfileActivity, viewProfileActivity::class.java)
                    finish()
                    startActivity(intent)

            }
            editAccountDetails() // main coroutine continues here immediately
            job.join()
        }

    }
```

I need the editAccountDetails() to be completed before finish() and start activity is carried out
Can someone please tell me what I am doing wrong?

--Edit editaccountDetails() code--

```
private fun editAccountDetails(){
        var username :String

        val usernameField = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.editTextUsername)

        userRefDoc = database.collection("users").document(userId!!)
        userRefDoc.get()
            .addOnSuccessListener { document ->
                if (document != null) {
                    username = (document.data?.getValue("fullname").toString())
                    if(usernameField.text.toString()!= username)
                    {
                        userRefDoc.update("fullname",usernameField.text.toString()).addOnFailureListener { e ->
                            val tempToast = Toast.makeText(this, "Error updating username", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                            tempToast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0)
                            tempToast.show()

                        }
                            .addOnSuccessListener { e ->
                                val tempToast=Toast.makeText(this, "Username has been updated", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                                tempToast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0)
                                tempToast.show()
                            }
                    }
                }
            }
        var email = (currentUser!!.email)
        val currentPasswordField = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.editCurrentPassword)
        val confirmPasswordField = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.editTextConfirmPassword)
        val newPasswordField = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.editTextNewPassword)
        val emailField = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.editTextEmail)

        if(emailField.text.toString() != email!! && newPasswordField.text.toString() != ""
            && confirmPasswordField.text.toString() != "") {
            if (currentPasswordField.text.toString() == "") {
                val tempToast = Toast.makeText(this, "Enter your current password", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                tempToast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0)
                return tempToast.show()
            } else {
                val pattern: Pattern
                val matcher: Matcher
                val specialCharacters = "-@%\\[\\}+'!/#$^?:;,\\(\"\\)~`.*=&\\{>\\]<_"
                val PASSWORD_REGEX =
                    "^(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[$specialCharacters])(?=\\S+$).{8,20}$"
                pattern = Pattern.compile(PASSWORD_REGEX)
                matcher = pattern.matcher(newPasswordField.text.toString())
                if (!matcher.matches()) {
                    val tempToast = Toast.makeText(
                        this,
                        "New password has to meet the requirements specified",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
                    )
                    tempToast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0)
                    return tempToast.show()
                } else if (newPasswordField.text.toString() != confirmPasswordField.text.toString()) {
                    val tempToast = Toast.makeText(this, "New passwords do no match", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    tempToast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0)
                    return tempToast.show()
                } else {
                    val newPassword = newPasswordField.text.toString()
                    val credential = EmailAuthProvider
                        .getCredential(email, currentPasswordField.text.toString())
                    currentUser?.reauthenticate(credential)
                        ?.addOnFailureListener {
                            Toast.makeText(
                                this,
                                "current password do not match",
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG
                            ).show()
                        }
                        ?.addOnSuccessListener {
                            currentUser?.updateEmail(emailField.text.toString())
                                ?.addOnCompleteListener { task ->
                                    if (task.isSuccessful) {
                                        val tempToast = Toast.makeText(
                                            this,
                                            "Successfully updated email password",
                                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
                                        )
                                        tempToast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0)
                                        tempToast.show()
                                        currentUser?.updatePassword(newPassword)
                                            ?.addOnCompleteListener { task2 ->
                                                if (task2.isSuccessful) {
                                                    val tempToast2 = Toast.makeText(
                                                        this,
                                                        "Successfully update password",
                                                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
                                                    )
                                                    tempToast2.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0)
                                                    tempToast2.show()
                                                }
                                            }
                                    }
                                }
                        }
                    return
                }

            }
        }

        //update email
        if(emailField.text.toString() != email){
            if(currentPasswordField.text.toString()=="")
            {
                val tempToast = Toast.makeText(this, "Enter your current password", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                tempToast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0)
                return tempToast.show()
            }
            else {
                val credential = EmailAuthProvider
                    .getCredential(email!!, currentPasswordField.text.toString())
                currentUser?.reauthenticate(credential)
                    ?.addOnFailureListener{
                        val tempToast = Toast.makeText(this, "current password do not match", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        tempToast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0)
                        tempToast.show()}
                    ?.addOnSuccessListener {
                        currentUser?.updateEmail(emailField.text.toString())
                            ?.addOnCompleteListener { task ->
                                if (task.isSuccessful) {
                                    email = emailField.text.toString()
                                    val tempToast = Toast.makeText(this, "Successfully updated email", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                                    tempToast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0)
                                    tempToast.show()
                                } else {
                                    val tempToast = Toast.makeText(this, "Error updating email", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                                    tempToast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0)
                                    tempToast.show()
                                }
                            }
                    }

            }
        }
        //update password
        if(newPasswordField.text.toString() != "" && currentPasswordField.text.toString() != "" && confirmPasswordField.text.toString() != ""){
            val pattern: Pattern
            val matcher: Matcher
            val specialCharacters = "-@%\\[\\}+'!/#$^?:;,\\(\"\\)~`.*=&\\{>\\]<_"
            val PASSWORD_REGEX = "^(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[$specialCharacters])(?=\\S+$).{8,20}$"
            pattern = Pattern.compile(PASSWORD_REGEX)
            matcher = pattern.matcher(newPasswordField.text.toString())
            if(!matcher.matches())
            {
                val tempToast = Toast.makeText(this, "New password has to meet the requirements specified", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                tempToast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0)
                return tempToast.show()
            }
            else if(newPasswordField.text.toString() != confirmPasswordField.text.toString())
            {
                val tempToast = Toast.makeText(this, "New passwords do no match", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                tempToast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0)
                return tempToast.show()
            }
            val newPassword = newPasswordField.text.toString()
            val credential = EmailAuthProvider
                .getCredential(email!!, currentPasswordField.text.toString())
            // Prompt the user to re-provide their sign-in credentials
            currentUser?.reauthenticate(credential)
                ?.addOnFailureListener {
                    val tempToast = Toast.makeText(this, "Current password does not tally", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    tempToast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0)
                    tempToast.show()}
                ?.addOnSuccessListener {
                    currentUser?.updatePassword(newPassword)
                        ?.addOnCompleteListener { task ->
                            if (task.isSuccessful) {
                                val tempToast = Toast.makeText(this, "Successfully update password", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                                tempToast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0)
                                tempToast.show()

                            }
                        }
                }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

`launch` starts a coroutine, but doesn't wait for the result. Your tasks that should happen before the events of the coroutine should go in the `launch` block itself.

`runBlocking` should not be used in Android apps. It's for using almost exclusively in the `main` function of a JVM app, or in tests. Otherwise, it defeats the purpose of using a coroutine because it blocks the thread.

`GlobalScope` should not be used to run coroutines that capture the Activity or Fragment, because then the Activity or Fragment can be leaked. This coroutine captures the Activity by calling `finish()` on it. Use `lifecycleScope` instead.

So if you fix all of the above, you should have something like:

```
submitBtn.setOnClickListener {
    lifecycleScope.launch {
        delay(5000L)
        editAccountDetails()
        val intent = Intent(this@editProfileActivity, viewProfileActivity::class.java)
        finish()
        startActivity(intent)
    }
}
```

However, since I don't know what you're doing with the five second delay or what `editAccountDetails()` does, you may need to rearrange it.

If `editAccountDetails()` is a long-running function that you don't want to block the main thread, you can wrap it in a `withContext(Dispatchers.Default){}` block, or make it a suspend function that wraps its own content in a `withContext`.

Comment: editAccountDetails consists of updating firebase with the relevant information. Upon successfully updating the database a toast should be reflected indicating that

However with this set of code, It is still starting a new activity before the editAccountDetails has finished running and displayed its appropriate toast

Comment: Can you show editAccountDetails? It should be converted into a suspend function.

Comment: You need to use Firebase Ktx so you can call the asynchronous functions as suspend functions. I don’t use Firebase. You can refer to the section on coroutines here: https://dev.to/rosariopfernandes/using-kotlin-extension-functions-and-coroutines-with-firebase-j0k

Answer (score 0):

If what you are trying to achieve is to finish the activity only after *editAccountDetails* method is finished and that methods takes times. You can call that method inside GlobalScope.launch {} and call finish when the job returned by it is finshed.

Your editAccountDetails() method seem to be making api calls, i would recommend replacing *GlobalScpoe.Launch* with *launch(Dispatchers.Default)*

The final version looks something like this.

```
submitBtn.setOnClickListener() {
    runBlocking {
        val job = launch(Dispatchers.Default) {
            editAccountDetails() 

        }
        job.join()
        val intent = Intent(this@editProfileActivity, viewProfileActivity::class.java)
        startActivity(intent)
        finish()
    }
}
```

Comment: i tried entering your code but it doesnt work. "Join should only only be called from a coroutine or a suspend function"